# Why is 'this' losing context in new Angular 1.5 components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

Got a very odd issue coming up here with the new components. When we had a 1.4 directive we had the following code...

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

angular.module('app.board').directive('dcCb', dcClipboardCopy);

  function dcCb() {
    return {
      link : function(scope, elem) {

        var clipboard = new Clipboard(elem[0]);

        elem.on('$destroy', function() {
          clipboard.destroy();
        });
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

Inside the `clipboard.destroy()` function is the following...

```
Clipboard.prototype.destroy = function(){
    this.listeners.destroy();
}
```

In 1.4 `this` is the same as the element so...

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-menu-outline copy-button" ...
```

So this worked fine as the button element seemed to have the `listeners` property which could be invoked.

However after the upgrade to 1.5 and now we have a component like this....

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.board').component('dcCb', {
...
    controller: [ '$element','$scope',function($element,$scope) {

      var self = this;
      self.$postLink = postLink;
      function postLink(){
        var clipboard = new Clipboard($element[0]);
...
        $element.on('$destroy', clipboard.destroy);
      }

    }]
  });
})();
```

`this` (when inside the destroy function of the Clipboard) is now the controller object. So trying to call `this.listeners` throws an error.

**First Question** :
I understand that `this` in new components is the component scope but in 1.4 it was the button element. Surely in both the button element should be $element? Were we doing something wrong in 1.4?

**Second Question** :
Shouldn't `var clipboard = new Clipboard($element[0])` force the context of `this` inside the clipboard to always be the clipboard itself (due to the `new` keyword)?

Comment: A bit confused; are you actually using the .component('name', {}) syntax and moving what used to be in the link function to the component controller? Or are you referring to something else when you say 'components in 1.5' ?

Comment: Code updated.....yes we are now using the .component function not the directive function.

Comment: you used the function very differently in your upgraded one... of course you lost `this`. in 1.4 you avoided this with an anonymous function.

Comment: Just because you created an instance of a class doesn't mean it keeps context when you pass a function that was part of the instance elsewhere. Anything can rebind it using .call or .apply. event handlers always do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're handing a function, which is arbitrarily defined on a class, off to the window and event listeners to be executed in a different context than the instance of Clipboard:

```
$element.on('$destroy', clipboard.destroy);
```

This is a fundamental concept of execution context in javascript, and I'd recommend reading up on it. But you can easily solve your current problem by simply binding the context of the function you are passing:

```
$element.on('$destroy', clipboard.destroy.bind(clipboard));
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain the exact reason why the context of this in a 1.4 style directive is the element yet in 1.5 it is the controller (and thus throws an exception). I appreciate your response and that is what I already tried (and it worked) however ```why``` has this changed?

Comment: In the 1.4 example you're passing an anonymous function to the "on" event listener. That function has a closure over parent scope which contains the instance of clipboard. When the anon func is later executed the instance of clipboard calls the method destroy. All good. In your 1.5 example you are just passing clipboard.destroy. That's just a function. It knows nothing of context whatever then later calls that function will be the context. The reason it changed is solely because you changed the code. I would read up on context and closures to learn more.